# How to dynamically test for available global variables in frameworks?

Tags: iphone, macos

As my iPhone app can run on both OS 3 and 4, I need a way to safely test for iOS 4 SDK features.

I like to avoid checking the [UIDevice ... systemVersion] string (I wonder why Apple failed to provide a numeric value here for easy testing, as it's available on OS X).

Anyway. The usual clean way to test for SDK features is to check if a class reponds to a selector, like this:

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:...
```

And for C methods, one simply checks if the function pointer is NULL:

```
if (newFunction != NULL) ...
```

But my problem is that I need to check if a global variable exists. E.g. this one:

```
extern NSString *const UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
```

Any idea how one can test their existence at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extracted from the help document [SDK Compatibility guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-1114537-BABHHJBC):

> Check the availability of an external (extern) constant or a notification name by explicitly comparing its address—and not the symbol’s bare name—to NULL or nil.

For instance, if you wanted to check for the key `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` in a keyboard notification dictionary, which is only available in 3.2 and later, you could write:

```
if (&UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) {
    blah;
} else {
    blah;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the default method is

```
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;

if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])

   backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
```

When the test is passed your "it exists in 4.x" global variable shoudl be available.

By the way - it answers if OS4 is there an if the device supports multitasking.
Manfred

Comment: Thanks for that hint towards device.multitaskingSupported. I had not been aware of it.

My question was more general, though, not specific to this particular feature. I like to know if there's a way to test for declared globals.